# How to sent from select table data to the backend so i can download somthing selected?

Tags: reactjs, express

Hi guys im working on project and i want to use this table 
http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table
after fix everything and make it work with my project i have this problem
what i want is to sent the information of the select one in the frontend to the back end so i can download the selected ones,
is there any simple way to do it ? 
Thanks for your helping :)
this is the code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Auth from '../modules/Auth';
import Dashboard from '../components/Dashboard.jsx';
import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableFooter,
  TableHeader,
  TableHeaderColumn,
  TableRow,
  TableRowColumn,
} from 'material-ui/Table';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import Toggle from 'material-ui/Toggle';


const styles = {
  propContainer: {
    width: 200,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    margin: '20px auto 0',
  },
  propToggleHeader: {
    margin: '20px auto 10px',
  },
};


class DashboardPage extends React.Component {

  /**
   * Class constructor.
   */
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    fixedHeader: true,
    fixedFooter: false,
    stripedRows: false,
    showRowHover: false,
    selectable: true,
    multiSelectable: true,
    enableSelectAll: true,
    deselectOnClickaway: true,
    showCheckboxes: true,
    height: '300px',
    tableData: []
    };

    this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleToggle (event, toggled){
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: toggled
    });
  };

  handleChange(event){
    this.setState({height: event.target.value});
  };








  componentDidMount() {

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', '/api/getdata');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    // set the authorization HTTP header
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `bearer ${Auth.getToken()}`);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';

    xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {

          this.setState({tableData: xhr.response});

      }
    });
    xhr.send();
  };

  handleClick() {
    let anchor = document.createElement("a");
    let file = 'http://localhost:3000/api/export';
    let headers = new Headers();

    headers.append('Authorization', `bearer ${Auth.getToken()}`);
    fetch(file, { headers })
          .then(response => response.blob())
          .then(blobby => {
              let objectUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobby);

              anchor.href = objectUrl;
              anchor.download = 'some-file.xlsx';
              anchor.click();

              window.URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
    });

};

  /**
   * Render the component.
   */
   render() {
   return (
      <div>
        <Table
          height={this.state.height}
          fixedHeader={this.state.fixedHeader}
          fixedFooter={this.state.fixedFooter}
          selectable={this.state.selectable}
          multiSelectable={this.state.multiSelectable}
        >
          <TableHeader
            displaySelectAll={this.state.showCheckboxes}
            adjustForCheckbox={this.state.showCheckboxes}
            enableSelectAll={this.state.enableSelectAll}
          >
            <TableRow>
              <TableHeaderColumn colSpan="7" tooltip="Super Header" style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                Super Header
              </TableHeaderColumn>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
              <TableHeaderColumn tooltip="ID">ID</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn tooltip="Name">Name</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn tooltip="Event">Event</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn tooltip="Email">Email</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn tooltip="Iban">Iban</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn tooltip="UID">UID</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn tooltip="Date">date</TableHeaderColumn>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody
            displayRowCheckbox={this.state.showCheckboxes}
            deselectOnClickaway={this.state.deselectOnClickaway}
            showRowHover={this.state.showRowHover}
            stripedRows={this.state.stripedRows}
          >
            {this.state.tableData.map((row, index) => (
              <TableRow key={index}>
                <TableRowColumn>{index}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{row.name}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{row.event}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{row.email}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{row.iban}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{row.uid}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{row.date}</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
              ))}
          </TableBody>
          <TableFooter
            adjustForCheckbox={this.state.showCheckboxes}
          >
            <TableRow>
              <TableRowColumn>ID</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>Name</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>Event</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>Email</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>Iban</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>UID</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>date</TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
              <TableRowColumn colSpan="7" style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                Super Footer
              </TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
          </TableFooter>
        </Table>
        <br/>

        <div>
          <RaisedButton label="Download"  fullWidth={true} onClick={this.handleClick} />
        </div>

        <div style={styles.propContainer}>
          <h3>Table Properties </h3>
          <TextField
            floatingLabelText="Table Body Height"
            defaultValue={this.state.height}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <Toggle
            name="fixedHeader"
            label="Fixed Header"
            onToggle={this.handleToggle}
            defaultToggled={this.state.fixedHeader}
          />
          <Toggle
            name="fixedFooter"
            label="Fixed Footer"
            onToggle={this.handleToggle}
            defaultToggled={this.state.fixedFooter}
          />
          <Toggle
            name="selectable"
            label="Selectable"
            onToggle={this.handleToggle}
            defaultToggled={this.state.selectable}
          />
          <Toggle
            name="multiSelectable"
            label="Multi-Selectable"
            onToggle={this.handleToggle}
            defaultToggled={this.state.multiSelectable}
          />
          <Toggle
            name="enableSelectAll"
            label="Enable Select All"
            onToggle={this.handleToggle}
            defaultToggled={this.state.enableSelectAll}
          />
          <h3 style={styles.propToggleHeader}>TableBody Properties</h3>
          <Toggle
            name="deselectOnClickaway"
            label="Deselect On Clickaway"
            onToggle={this.handleToggle}
            defaultToggled={this.state.deselectOnClickaway}
          />
          <Toggle
            name="stripedRows"
            label="Stripe Rows"
            onToggle={this.handleToggle}
            defaultToggled={this.state.stripedRows}
          />
          <Toggle
            name="showRowHover"
            label="Show Row Hover"
            onToggle={this.handleToggle}
            defaultToggled={this.state.showRowHover}
          />
          <h3 style={styles.propToggleHeader}>Multiple Properties</h3>
          <Toggle
            name="showCheckboxes"
            label="Show Checkboxes"
            onToggle={this.handleToggle}
            defaultToggled={this.state.showCheckboxes}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default DashboardPage;
```

and this is the backend

```
//***************************Download **************************//

router.get("/export",(req,res) => {

  console.log("Uids" ,req.body);

  var productId = req.body.productIds;
  var productArr = [];
                   if( typeof productId === "string") {
                        productId = [productId];
                    }else{
                      productArr.push(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(productId));
                    }

      console.log("Uids" ,req.body);              

  var conf ={};
                  //conf.stylesXmlFile = "styles.xml";
                    conf.name = "mysheet";
                    conf.cols = [{
                                  caption:'name',
                                  type:'string'
                                },{
                                  caption:'event',
                                  type:'string'        
                                },{
                                  caption:'email',
                                  type:'string'        
                                },{
                                  caption:'iban',
                                  type:'string'        
                                },{
                                  caption:'uid',
                                  type:'string'        
                                },{
                                  caption:'date',
                                  type:'date'        
                    }];

                    conf.rows = [];
                    User.find({'_id': { $in: productArr }}, function(err, allUid){
                        if (err) {
                            res.send(err);
                            console.log(productArr);
                        }
                         for(var i= 0; i < allUid.length; i++) {
                            var tempdate = "";
                             try {
                                 tempdate = new Date(allUid[i].date).toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '');
                             } catch(err) {
                                 console.log("Error: ", err);
                             }

                            conf.rows.push([
                                allUid[i].name,
                                allUid[i].event,
                                allUid[i].email,
                                allUid[i].iban,
                                allUid[i].uid,
                                tempdate
                            ]);
                        }

                        var result = nodeExcel.execute(conf);
                        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats');
                        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Report.xlsx");
                        res.end(result, 'binary');
                    });
});


module.exports = router;
```